# Java Order by on one to many relationship with different child object type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

**Question**

I need sort the ExamObjects according to the `id` if the `ExamObject` is of `ExamTask` and sort it according to the `questionNumber` if it's `ExamQuestion`. How can I do this?

**Important**

An exam will only have a set of `ExamTask` or `ExamQuestion`. In other words, one exam cannot have a mixture of ExamTask and ExamQuestion.

**Background Information**

I have an Entity class called `Exam` This class can contain one or more `ExamObject` entities.

```
@Entity
public class Exam {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "exam" ...)
   @OrderBy("id") //I need to order this by question number if its ExamQuestion
   private Set<ExamObject> objects;
   ...
}
```

`ExamObject` can be of two types as below using `JOINED`

1. `ExamTask` extends `ExamObject`
2. `ExamQuestion` which extends `ExamObject` and has a column called `questionNumber`

**`ExamObject`**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class ExamObject {    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    ...
```

**`ExamTask`**

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
public class ExamTask extends ExamObject{
   ...
```

**`ExamQuestion`**

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
public class ExamQuestion extends ExamObject{
   @Column(name = "question_number")
   private Integer questionNumber;
   ...
```

Comment: Out of curiosity , tried replicating your problem, but I cant seem to get the mapping to work. Posted another question because of this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764533/hibernate-inheritance-strategy-inheritancetype-joined-onetomany-with-spring-da

Comment: Didn't know one was allowed to use magic (OrderBy annotation) in code. Thanks for that good fellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By declaring the set to be of type `TreeSet` and providing a `Comparator` to the constructor, inserted items will be sorted automatically.

```
new TreeSet<ExamObject>(new Comparator<ExamObject>(){

    @Override
    public int compare(ExamObject a, ExamObject b){
        int q1 = 0, q2 = 0;
        if(a instanceof ExamQuestion){
            q1 = ((ExamQuestion)a).questionNumber;
            if(b instanceof ExamQuestion){
                q2 = ((ExamQuestion)b).questionNumber;
            }else{
                q2 = ((ExamTask)b).id;
            }
        }else{
            q1 = ((ExamTask)a).id;
            if(b instanceof ExamQuestion){
                q2 = ((ExamQuestion)b).questionNumber;
            }else{
                q2 = ((ExamTask)b).id;
            }
        }
        if(q1 == q2) return 0;
        else return q1 < q2  ? -1 : 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: That's neat and awesome. Thanks alot. :) I will upvote your answer but will wait for sometime without selecting it to see if there are any other possibilities in which the logic can be run in the database itself using some annotations.  I'm switching my project codes to what you have suggested right now. :)

Comment: @FarajFarook If you feel I provided the best answer, please mark it as correct so people know it has been answered appropriately.

Answer (score 7):

I believe your issue is that you are using a Set in your entity. A Set will not maintain order. When your relationship is loaded the set will not guarantee insertion order. Try using a List instead. The List will maintain the insertion order.

```
@Entity
public class Exam {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "exam" ...)
   @OrderBy("id") //I need to order this by question number if its ExamQuestion
   private List<ExamObject> objects;
   ...
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: No problem using @OrderBy over a Set collection.

Answer (score 5):

I used @OrderBy with Set and it works fine.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "mailing", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@OrderBy("documentPrintOrder ASC")
private Set<MailingDocsEntity> mailingDocs = new HashSet<MailingDocsEntity>();
```

Comment: This one works for me. I had to convert the returned POJO (mailingDocs here) to VO, so used List<> in place of Set<> to make sure the insertion oder is preserved.