# Hibernate Inheritance strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED & onetoMany with spring-data-jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

For Some reason, I am not able to get the combination of Hibernate Inheritance strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED & onetoMany working. Following are the entities.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="OBJECT_TYPE")
public abstract class ExamObject {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "examid", nullable = false)
        private Exam exam;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Q")
public class ExamQuestion extends ExamObject{

     private Integer questionNumber;

     private String questionDesc;
}
```

@Entity

```
public class Exam {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer examid;

    private String examName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "exam")
    private Set<ExamObject> object
}
```

My Spring Boot start up class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ExamApp implements CommandLineRunner {
@Autowired
    private ExamQuestionRepository examQuestionRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ExamRepository examRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExamApp.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        Exam exam = new Exam();
        exam.setExamName("Exam1");
        examRepository.save(exam);

        String[] questions = new String[]{"Question1,Question2"};
        ArrayList<ExamQuestion> examQuestions = new ArrayList<ExamQuestion();
        int index = 0;
        for(String questionNoDesc: questions){
            index++;
            ExamQuestion examQuestion = new ExamQuestion();
            examQuestion.setQuestionDesc(questionNoDesc);
            examQuestion.setQuestionNumber(index);
            examQuestion.setExam(exam);
            examQuestions.add(examQuestion);
        }
        examQuestionRepository.save(examQuestions);

        Iterable<Exam> examGet = examRepository.findAll();
        for (Exam exam2: examGet) {
             System.out.println("Exam question is .. " +exam2.getObjects());
        }
    }
 }
```

The problems is that whenever I print `"Exam question is .. "+exam2.getObjects()`, I always get null. How can I get this to work ?

Comment: That's expected: your code never assigns anything to `exam.object`, so it's null. `exam2` and `exam` both point to the exact same object.

Comment: I have mapped exam.object with onetoMany. So I am expecting it to provide me the list of examobject for the exam when I retrieve the exam.

Comment: You're doing everything in a single transaction. So the exam you're persisting is stored as is in the first-level (session) cache. When you execute a query, Hibernate returns this same instance already in the cache. It's your responsibility to maintain the coherence of the object graph: if you set an question's exam, then this question should be added to the exam's objects.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comment in the original question, the problem is that the object graph is not being maintained properly. One extra line of code to the following function fixed the issue.  `exam.setObjects(examQuestions);`has been added

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        Exam exam = new Exam();
        exam.setExamName("Exam1");
        examRepository.save(exam);

        String[] questions = new String[]{"Question1,Question2"};
        ArrayList<ExamQuestion> examQuestions = new ArrayList<ExamQuestion();
        int index = 0;
        for(String questionNoDesc: questions){
            index++;
            ExamQuestion examQuestion = new ExamQuestion();
            examQuestion.setQuestionDesc(questionNoDesc);
            examQuestion.setQuestionNumber(index);
            examQuestion.setExam(exam);
            examQuestions.add(examQuestion);
        }
        examQuestionRepository.save(examQuestions);
        exam.setObjects(examQuestions);

        Iterable<Exam> examGet = examRepository.findAll();
        for (Exam exam2: examGet) {
             System.out.println("Exam question is .. " +exam2.getObjects());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the issue is

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "exam")
    private Set object

When you fetch any thing by LAZY loading `FetchType.LAZY`. This will get all the object from teh parent table i.e Exam here but will not query the child/dependent tables for the data.

e.g Here it will not hit the ExamObject to get its data, it just replaces this by the proxy object, Thus if you query this object then you get null as the result.

Try your query with `FetchType.EAGER`

Comment: The answer in the comment above is right. Problem was with my understanding of transactions. The fetch type did not create an issue for me. Thanks for the answer.